# Which ones of these two shows that the tensor product operation on two multilinear functions is bilinear?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, proof-writing, linear-transformations, tensor-products

Suppose $v \in V_1 \times \cdots \times V_k$ and $w \in W_1\times \cdots \times W_l$. The tensor product of $F \in L(V_1 \times \cdots \times V_k, \mathbb R)$ and $G \in L(W_1 \times \cdots \times W_l, \mathbb R)$ is defined by 
$$F\otimes G(v,w)=F(v)G(w).$$

---

> If $F \in L(V_1 \times \cdots \times V_k, \mathbb R)$ and $G \in L(W_1 \times \cdots \times W_l, \mathbb R)$, how do we show that the tensor product operation is bilinear on $F$ and $G$?

Do we have to show that $$F\otimes G(av_1+bv_2, w)=aF\otimes G(v_1,w)+bF\otimes G(v_2,w)?$$

Or do we have to show that $$(aF_1+bF_2)\otimes G(v,w)=aF_1\otimes G(v,w)+bF_2\otimes G(v,w)?$$

Comment: You have to show the first, and the second one is *definition* of $aF_{1} + bF_{2}$ I think.

Comment: What exactly do you refer to when you say "the tensor product $F \otimes G$"? Given two linear maps $f : V \to V'$ and $g : W \to W'$, one can form the "tensor product" of these maps to be $f \otimes g : V \otimes W \to V' \otimes W'$ given by $(f \otimes g)(v \otimes w) = f(v) \otimes g(w)$. Is this the tensor product in question?

Comment: @S.O. I've edited the post.

Comment: @SeewooLee I edited the question. I must show that the tensor product operation is bilinear on $F$ and $G$. I think the second one is now correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that the tensor product operation is bilinear *on* $F$ and $G$, we must show:

$$(aF_1+F_2)\otimes G(v,w)=aF_1\otimes G(v,w)+F_2\otimes G(v,w),$$
$$F\otimes (aG_1 +G_2)(v,w)=F\otimes aG_1(v,w)+F\otimes G_2(v,w).$$

---

Your first one: $F\otimes G(av_1+bv_2, w)=aF\otimes G(v_1,w)+bF\otimes G(v_2,w)$ does not show that the tensor product is bilinear on $F$ and $G$. It just shows that it is linear in the arguments of the tensor product, but we already know this since $F$ and $G$ are both multi-linear functions.